# Change language firebase_ui_auth using strings.xml

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to change the language of my flutter application that uses the firebase_ui_auth library

I added the resConfigs parameter 'es' in the build.gradle file and created the values-en folder but it doesn't work.

SC:

Answer (score 1):

First, ***please don't put the full git repository into a question*** - it contains sensitive information and keys please avoid this ... please try to put a problem `code` snippet.
Stackoverflow is not responsible for your security - is someone debugging your code with your all information?

[image]